# “Ctrl”+“X” no longer working after installing Unity/MonoDevelop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

So the title basically explains my issue.

My <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> stopped working after I installed the [Unity Game development engine](http://unity3d.com/5) which uses MonoDevelop for an IDE.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? How do I resolve this?

It stopped working overall, also in Notepad and so on.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of keyboard failure? You could boot a Linux distro off of a Live CD and use the shortcut there to confirm whether or not the problem lies with your keyboard or if it's only restricted to Windows.

Comment: It is not a keyboard issue, both the keyboard on my laptop itself as an external keyboard do not make it work.

Comment: I wonder if this is a [keyboard ghosting](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx) issue. Can you [check](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/content/projects/KeyboardGhostingDemo.aspx) if that's the case with both keyboards?

Answer (score 0):

Try to view keyboard hooks with [AVZ](http://support.kaspersky.com/common/service.aspx?el=1698) ([download link](http://z-oleg.com/avz4.zip)).

For example: I have [PuntoSwitcher](http://punto.yandex.ru/) installed to quickly switch <kbd>RU</kbd>\<kbd>EN</kbd> keyboard layouts and fix text typed in wrong layout. It hooks keyboard input to do this with `pshook.dll`.

1. Run AVZ
2. From <kbd>Service</kbd> menu select <kbd>Injected DLLs Manager</kbd>

   [image: Main AVZ window]
3. Look for any suspicious dlls

   [image: PuntoSwitcher hook]